# HTML: Why there's so many class names

Tags: html, css

Why there's so many class names like home, page-template-default, page, page-id-12. When I should use so many ones? Isn't it enough one class name?

`<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-12 webp">`

Answer (score 1):

You can technically just use one if you prefer that but the problem there is you won't be able to reuse some styles and it'll be difficult to update if you do decide to copy paste it to a bunch of classnames

For example

```
.card {
padding: 10px;
background-color: white;
border: black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.card-blue {
background-color: blue;
}
.card-red {
background-color: red;
}
```

with the .card class you can add it to multple elements and add more classes to have customization without repeating multiple css lines.

```
<div class="card card-red">Red Card</div>
<div class="card card-blue">Blue Card</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because those all class's default adding from CMS.

If you want to add css for all pages, You can use the **"page"** as a class in css.

```css
body.page{ }
```

If you want to add css only for homepage, You can use the **"home"** as a class in css.

```css
body.home{ }
```

If you want to add css based on page id, You can use the **"page-id-12"** as a class in css.

```css
body.page-id-12{ }
```